# Issue with Slow Sandisk Extreme 1Tb with MBPro mid 2014

Tags: macos

Very slow in write performance with 1Tb Sandisk Extreme MicroSD with Low profile adapter, for MBPro mid 2014, 15 inch Retina.

Done many Search, even here, without no success.

Running Big Sur 10.14

Looking for complete, Terminal Commands, to solve this issue.

Comment: You've changed your question after the answer was posted. You still haven't provided any actual data. What speeds are you getting & what do you *think* you ought to get?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you have a new question, please ask it as a separate question. Your text I removed is still in the revision history should you want to copy it for a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum transfer rates are going to be slow compared to what the card can theoretically achieve. Macbooks with card slots run at USB 2 speeds.

From the [Apple KB - About the SD and SDXC card slot on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204384)

> **How fast can my Mac read or write to an SD card in the SD card slot?**
> Mac notebooks use the USB bus to communicate with the SD card slot. They have a maximum speed of up to 480 Mbit/s. Mac desktops use the PCIe bus to communicate with the SD card slot. Desktops can transfer data at a faster rate.

Comment: You asked why it was slow. If you need further help best to ask a second question rather than a comment attached to this one